# Como detectar auto se o aparelho esta na horizontal em java

Tags: java, android

Quero fazer um script em **Java** pra detectar se o aparelho esta na horizontal ou na vertical, com if else, quero pra se estiver na horizontal esconde automaticamente a barra de navegação do aparelho em `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);`

e se na vertical exibir a barra de navegação, alguém sábio para me instruir?

Comment: É uma velha pergunta aqui do site, mas tive dificuldade de localizar e agora não estou com tempo para fazê-lo. Tentei procurando por Android horizontal rotation e coisas assim. Talvez nas tags tenha alguma coisa. Se alguém encontrar por favor marque como duplicada.

Comment: Mas pensando melhor acho que isso se resolve com XMLs separados para os layouts vertical e horizontal, seria uma coisa a ser pesquisada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode detectar a orientação do aparelho sobrescrevendo método `onConfigurationChanged`  , como abaixo:

```
 @Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
      if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
         //horizontal
      } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
         //vertical
      }
   }
```

[Exemplo na documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes#java)

Comment: Obrigado isso mesmo resolveu